# Make Tkinter widget take focus

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a script that uses Tkinter to pop up a window with a message. How do I make sure it takes focus so the user doesn't miss it and explicitly has to dismiss the window. the code is :

```
root = Tk()
to_read = "Stuff" 
w = Label(root, text=to_read)
w.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `focus_force` method.  See the following:

- [Universal widget methods](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/universal.html)

But note the the documentation:

> w.focus_force()
>
> Force the input focus to the widget. This is impolite. It's better to wait for the window manager to give you the focus. See also .grab_set_global() below.

Update: It should work on `root`.  For example, try running the following code.  It will create a window and you can switch focus.  After 5 seconds, it will try to grab the focus.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.after(5000, lambda: root.focus_force())
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: the command is ok, but where does it go in my code? It seems my format will be root.focus_force, but it give an Attribute error.

Comment: it seems to be working now. I left out the .after function though. thanks.

Comment: @Ali: the `after` wasn't necessary: it was only to introduce a delay before forcing focus so I could start the application and have enough time to shift focus to another application for demonstration purposes.  Glad it's working for you now.  :)

Comment: @ars, how to `focus_force` for a `Text` widget when you run the program? Because I have used `focus_force`, but there's a problem: both `IDLE` and the `tinter.Text` widget have their own cursor, but when I try to write, it writes on the interactive IDLE shell and not on the `tinter.Text` widget, even if there's also a cursor there.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was:

```
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
root.focus_force()
```

I found this and some other way to do it in win32 [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2006-May/004678.html)