# set focus to Tkinter window in Python (and OS X)

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Consider the following MWE:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
Label(root,text="foo").pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I want to set a newly created `Tkinter` window that does not include any "focusable" controls like buttons to the foreground. If I run the code above (from a shell), the window is inactive and therefore not able to react to key bindings.

Is there any way to bring such a window to the foreground?

[Edit]
I am using Python 2.7.5 and OS X Mavericks. I run the code from a terminal window and the focus stays at that window even though the Tkinter window is created properly.

Comment: did you check that post ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842220/make-tkinter-widget-take-focus

Comment: @mlwn yes, it didn't work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just tried it on IDLE:

```
>>> from Tkinter import *
>>> root=Tk()
>>> root.focus_force()
>>> Label(root,text="foo").pack()
>>> root.mainloop()
```

Worked like a charm!(Edit: on Windows apparently!)

Edit:[This is a standard behavior](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-September/551195.html)

Comment: works for me exactly the same with or without root.focus_force()

Comment: & was the focus on the new window? Because it was not the case in mine

Comment: window came to the foreground using both, biggest problem was it was so small. I think it is a platform specific issue.

Comment: Being small isn't an issue,it was made so by the OP. The problem was that it wasn't getting focus

Comment: it was getting focus for me using both methods so as I said it is probably platform specific.

Comment: yeah..probably. I was trying it on windows,what platform are you using?

Comment: ubuntu, I was a T.A on a course where we used Tkinter, a lot of people using mac had similar issues.

Comment: Well I'm on windows & also facing the same issue

Comment: @shaktimaan won't work for me, the result stays the same

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're doing something wrong, because below works perfectly for me:
could be platform issue ??

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
Label(root,text="foo").pack()

root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (200,100,0,0))
#made it a bigger window to see better...
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
root.focus_force()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: won't work for me (python 2.7.5, OS X Mavericks) when executed from command line. The focus stays at the terminal window and is not switched to the window.

Comment: Guess what, your first example works for me... I don't even need to call root.wm_attributes and root.focus_force...  I am using LinuxMint, and call it from terminal... I guess it's about the platform... and I am not familiar with apple :((((

Comment: @muffel: MAybe you could try to put some button inside, and hide it.. hopefully it can catch the focus ?? (as a workaround)