# Getting a pop up canvas to take focus

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How do I transfer keyboard control from one canvas to another

```
self.canvas.bind('<FocusOut>')
self.canvas2.bind('<FocusIn>')
```

doesn't work, the focus is still on canvas one and the keyboard still acts on canvas one not canvas two.

As well

```
self.canvas2.focus_set()
```

still keeps the focus on self.canvas and not on self.canvas2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Tkinter widget take focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842220/make-tkinter-widget-take-focus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`focus_set` is how you give focus to a widget.

Here's an example that shows two canvases, and sets the focus when you click one of the canvases. When you press the "s" key, a square will be drawn on whichever canvas has the focus.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def draw_square(event):
    x0 = random.randint(30, 370)
    y0 = random.randint(30, 170)
    size = random.randint(10, 30)

    event.widget.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x0+size, y0+size, fill="red")

def give_focus(event):
    event.widget.focus_set()
    event.widget.configure(background="bisque")

def lose_focus(event):
    event.widget.configure(background="white")

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="Click to focus a canvas, press 's' to draw a square")
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=200, background="white",
                    borderwidth=1, relief="raised")
canvas2 = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=200, background="white",
                    borderwidth=1, relief="raised")

label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
canvas1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
canvas2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

for canvas in (canvas1, canvas2):
    canvas.bind("<FocusOut>",lose_focus)
    canvas.bind("<1>", give_focus)
    canvas.bind("<s>", draw_square)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Strange, focus_set() wouldn't work for me this morning but as I've been trying to come up with a dumbed down version of the code, focus_set() is now working.  Thanks